# How to find Specific values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have imported the data in csv format in pandas. Can anybody tell me how i can find the values above 280 in one of the columns that i have and put them into another data frame. I have done the below code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('...csv')
```

And the part of data is like the attached pic:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q47pw.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

You need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df[2] > 280]
```

If need select also only column add [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = df.loc[df[2] > 280, 2]
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3],
                   1:[4,5,6],
                   2:[107,800,300],
                   3:[1,3,5]})

print (df)
   0  1    2  3
0  1  4  107  1
1  2  5  800  3
2  3  6  300  5

df1 = df[df[2] > 280]
print (df1)
   0  1    2  3
1  2  5  800  3
2  3  6  300  5

s = df.loc[df[2] > 280, 2]
print (s)
1    800
2    300
Name: 2, dtype: int64

#one column df
df2 = df.loc[df[2] > 280, [2]]
print (df2)
     2
1  800
2  300
```

Comment: Well explained. However, I wonder why `[2]` at the last command makes the difference?

Comment: Hmm, in my opinion it is same as subset - if want select only some columns use `df[[0,2]]` and if select only one use df[2]]

Comment: You can also use column names. For example, `df[df.columnName > 280]`

Comment: Yes, that's true. You can access through both `.` and `[]`

Comment: Yes, exactly. I like dot more, but generally it is better `[]`, because `.` cannot be used if column is number, if column nmae is same as pandas function `mean`, `sum`, ... - check [warning](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access).